# Compile MPAndroidChart lib with jar output instead of aar

Tags: gradle, mpandroidchart

How do I compile the MPAndroidChart library as jar instead of an aar? If I run gradle assembleDebug it will generate me an aar, but I see in the old MPAndroidChart distributions that they already provided a jar dependency.

I didn't find anything realted to gradle compile instructions in the readme file. Also "gradle tasks" didn't help me.

Any help here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked a while ago, but this is a reference for future developers.

1. Create an eclipse project, with the exact package structure that you see on the Android `MPAndroidChartLib` (https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/releases)
2. convert the project to a Maven project (right-click, configure, convert to maven project.
3. replace the generated `pom.xml` with the following :

   ```
   <project 
       xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
       <groupId>com.github.mikephil</groupId>
       <artifactId>MPAndroidChart</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <name>MPAndroidChart</name>
       <description>A simple Android chart view/graph view library, supporting line- bar- and piecharts as well as scaling, dragging and animations</description>
       <url>https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart</url>
       <packaging>jar</packaging>

       <build>
           <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>3.3</version>
                   <configuration>
                       <source>1.7</source>
                       <target>1.7</target>
                   </configuration>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </build>

       <properties>
           <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
       </properties>

       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
               <artifactId>android</artifactId>
               <scope>provided</scope>
               <version>4.1.1.4</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>junit</groupId>
               <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
               <version>4.12</version>
               <scope>test</scope>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
               <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
               <version>1.9.5</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>

       <issueManagement>
           <url>https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues</url>
           <system>GitHub Issues</system>
       </issueManagement>

       <licenses>
           <license>
               <name>Apache License Version 2.0</name>
               <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
               <distribution>repo</distribution>
           </license>
       </licenses>

       <scm>
           <url>https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart</url
           <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart.git</connection>
           <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:PhilJay/MPAndroidChart.git</developerConnection>
       </scm>

       <developers>
           <developer>
               <name>Philipp Jahoda</name>
               <email>philjay.librarysup@gmail.com</email>
               <url>http://stackoverflow.com/users/1590502/philipp-jahoda</url>
               <id>PhilJay</id>
           </developer>
       </developers>

   </project>
   ```
4. right-click on the pom and click on `maven install`
5. you'll find the jar under : `/target`